# Why is tomcat returning status 403

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I've a tomcat 9 server with a Spring boot application. When making a http request I get a 403 response back from Tomcat. But I don't know how to solve this issue. The only log file which show a 403 is localhost_access_log.2022-06-15.txt. But this doesn't bring me any further.
Where else can I look to solve this issue ?

localhost_access_log.2022-06-15.txt

**"POST /ta/calculateWithPrices HTTP/1.1" 403 5**  :  this is the only indication that a 403 is returned.

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Jun/2022:11:46:15 +0200] "GET /ta/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/ta/v3/api-docs/swagger-config HTTP/1.1" 200 1417
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Jun/2022:11:46:15 +0200] "GET /ta/swagger-ui/swagger-ui.css HTTP/1.1" 200 143753
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Jun/2022:11:46:15 +0200] "GET /ta/swagger-ui/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js HTTP/1.1" 200 337217
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Jun/2022:11:46:15 +0200] "GET /ta/swagger-ui/swagger-ui-bundle.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1091138
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Jun/2022:11:46:16 +0200] "GET /ta/v3/api-docs/swagger-config HTTP/1.1" 200 254
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Jun/2022:11:46:16 +0200] "GET /ta/swagger-ui/favicon-32x32.png HTTP/1.1" 200 628
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Jun/2022:11:46:16 +0200] "GET /ta/v3/api-docs HTTP/1.1" 200 1722
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Jun/2022:11:46:23 +0200] "POST /ta/calculateWithPrices HTTP/1.1" 403 5
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Jun/2022:11:48:49 +0200] "GET /ta/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/ta/v3/api-docs/swagger-config HTTP/1.1" 304 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Jun/2022:11:48:49 +0200] "GET /ta/v3/api-docs/swagger-config HTTP/1.1" 200 254
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Jun/2022:11:48:49 +0200] "GET /ta/v3/api-docs HTTP/1.1" 200 1722
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Jun/2022:11:49:37 +0200] "POST /ta/calculateWithPrices HTTP/1.1" 403 5
```

Comment: Is `/ta/calculateWithPrices` your code? What does it do? Does it have an access right check?

Comment: That is part of the request url which is called.  "/ta" is the domain ,  "/calculateWithPrices" is the  request mapping.

Comment: As this is related to your code: Please post a [mcve] and see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I have seen some people say that's because 403 server refused the request. It can be understood that you do not have permission to access this website. The server can receive the request but refuse to provide services.

Comment: ok...and where should I add this permission ?  On the application side, there is no security setup at all.  And I want to keep it like that.